# Django: Can we enforce POST request in DRF without requiring csrftoken?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf

I am implementing a `post commenting` mechanism in DRF using `ListCreateAPIView`. Using ReactJS, I wanna allow anonymous visitors to comment on a post. I am able to do so only when the `csrftoken` is available *(which means a user must be logged in for the `csrftoken` to be available)*.

But I wanna enforce commenting for unauthenticated users/anonymous site visitors. Do you guys know any way to do this, maybe without requiring csrftoken. Or if the token is really needed, is there any way to generate it without relying on Django's authentication process?

I'm knew to Django I badly need direction for this feature I'm developing.

Thanks a heap!

**views.py**

```
class APIListCreate__PostComment(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset            = PostComment.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    serializer_class    = PostCommentSerializer
    permission_classes  = [permissions.AllowAny]
    pagination_class    = None
    filter_backends     = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class     = APICustomFilter__PostComment

    def get_queryset(self):
        # this code block aims to paginate result
        # when 'pagination=True' query param is detected in the URL
        if self.request.query_params.get('pagination'):
            if self.request.query_params.get('pagination') == 'True':
                self.pagination_class = APIPagination
        return self.queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

**DRF settings**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add your view class as well as your `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings?

Comment: Hi @JPG I've updated my question above. Thanks!